# How to suppress WPF global app theme for User Control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes

I have **Expression Dark theme** for the **entire** WPF application.

```
<Application x:Uid="Application_1" x:Class="MyShow.Player.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             SessionEnding="App_SessionEnding" >
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Uid="ResourceDictionary_1"  >
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Uid="ResourceDictionary_3" Source="/Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

What I have is that this Expression Dark applies to all User Controls ( `public partial class UControl : UserControl`).

What I want is **to use totally different theme like Aero** or something else for all WPF User Controls.

How I can do it?

Thank you!

Comment: @jberger   It is  public partial class UControl : UserControl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Startup event and set the theme in the Startup event Handler. That theme will be applied all user control in that solution. In your case.

```
//App.xaml

<Application x:Uid="Application_1" x:Class="MyShow.Player.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
             SessionEnding="App_SessionEnding"
             Startup="Application_Startup">

//App.xaml.cs

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            StyleManager.ApplicationTheme = new MetroTheme(); //Set your theme           
        }
```